# How to reduce the APK size in case of a wallpaper app on Android

Tags: android

I am looking to create a wallpaper app on android which has a gridview with image thumbnails(PNGs) which expand on touch to show the full size and high res JPG image. I have also tried using PNGs for the full size images, but all the online sources I found let me keep a maximum size of 512X512 which isn't good enough for a wallpaper. What is the way out here to keep a good quality image while at the same time keep the size under check ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a good image compressor, but it might not be enough.

You can also keep your wallpapers on a server and pull them when opening the app. It's simple and lite. Create some thumbnails for the preview in order to preserve user's data.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to use [TinyPNG](https://tinypng.com/), which is a pretty good image compressor. I've had excelent results regarding file sizes.